# Format CSS file (compress/uncompress)

Tags: css, windows, visual-studio-2008, formatting

I want to format my css files used in my web project.

Formatting means: **Compress/Uncompress CSS file**

*Example:*

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}body{min-height:101%;font:69%/141% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#2d3742;}
```

to:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 101%;
  font: 69%/141% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color: #2d3742;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff url('../gfx/bgs/bg-body.gif') repeat-x;
}
```

It is pretty easy to do this with TextMate which I'm using at home. But **how can I do it with Visual Studio?** (couldn't find that feature) Or if there is no way to do it with VS, is there any windows program your aware of that is providing this feature?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/](http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compress these quickly online with the [CSS Compressor](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressoradvanced/). And fix the compression using the answer provided in [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276093/format-css-file-compress-uncompress/2276148#2276148): <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can well form the doc with key sequence

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> in Visual Studio

....

Thanks Jonathan Sampson for the `<kbd>` tags :)

Comment: +1 good answer. To the OP, you can use CTRL+K+D to format almost any file type (CSS, HTML, ASPX, XML, C#, VB, ETC). CTRL+K+F is an alternate keystroke which will format only the highlighted area.

Comment: @KP Cool I didn't know the alternate one, thanks for the tip. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use
[Css compressor](http://javascriptcompress.herokuapp.com/css/) to compress single or multiple css files